# How to create offer tag with css and pass value to it

Tags: html, css

I need to create a offer tag and pass a value to it. if 2 then the tag should be styles as described in below image. Any help will be appreciated. here is fiddle what I tried so far. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ukff2bbb/) 
but the text is not aligned and also I am passing awards from div, awards should be default present on tag. 
**UPDATE**
Ok no need to pass value but atleast is it possible to create a tag. I will pass value using jquery.
 [image: awards 2]

```css
div {
    width: 120px;
    margin-top: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: yellow;
    /* Rotate div */
    -ms-transform: rotate(7deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div>2 awards</div>
```

Comment: this question made minimal sense. what is passing the value 2 into it? you cannot "create" an offer tag with CSS. CSS is styling for the tag, not the scripting/markup language which creates it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic content delivered by CSS from some kind of input?  Normally I'd say no but this is actually possible now with the content attribute.  Something along these lines:

```css
.item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.item img {
  display:block;
}
.item.promoted:after {
  content: attr(data-awards) ' Awards';
  position: absolute;
  background: #C55;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(30%,-25%);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="item promoted" data-awards="2">
  <img src="//placehold.it/150" alt="promoted image">
</div>

<div class="item promoted" data-awards="7">
  <img src="//placehold.it/150" alt="promoted image">
</div>

<div class="item promoted" data-awards="5">
  <img src="//placehold.it/150" alt="promoted image">
</div>
```

Comment: Sir I have another tag at upper right corner of the image, is it possible to add with same div? can you update please??

Comment: @Sudarshan Do you mean a second tag?  You can add a `:before` element just like the `:after` element to the same div, but if you want any more than just the two, you need to create a wrapper element and use its `:before` and `:after`, giving you up to four.

Comment: Yeah got it thank you so much :-), created :before with different styles to align it right side.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this is what you want..

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
}
span {
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: orange;
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 24px;
  right: -26px;
  top: 22px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>2 Awards</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Its little bigger than the actual image can you fix this

Comment: Done shrinking to 120px width. Not sure how much you need, just tweak the CSS if you still want smaller. :)